# Android SearchView: Clear its focus and setOnSearchClick

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, searchview

You can try this to remove the focus from SearchView and something else if you want to set setOnSearchClickListener and it isn't worked when `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` or             `searchView.isIconified = false`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```kotlin
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(QueryTextListener(searchView))

class QueryTextListener(private val searchView: SearchView) : OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        // do something
        searchView.clearFocus()
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```